# datejs parsing some month is not working

Tags: javascript, date, datejs

I'm using date-fr-FR.js

When I'm doing this

```
Date.parse("5 juillet 2012")
```

it's returning null

But when I do this

```
Date.parse("5 juil. 2012")
```

it's returning the right date, someone have an idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source for [fr-FR.js](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/src/globalization/fr-FR.js?r=191A) (r191) which is used to build date-fr-FR.js, there seems to be is a mistake in the regular expressions that are used to determine the months, for that particular month it reads:

```
jul: /^juil(.(let)?)?/i,
```

which means it'll work with `Date.parse("5 juilXlet 2012")`, `Date.parse("5 juil 2012")` and `Date.parse("5 juil. 2012")` but not with `Date.parse("5 juillet 2012")`!

I think it should be something like this:

```
/^juil(\.|(let))?/i
```

Not that that will be of any help to you!  I suggest you just always use the short names unless you can get that file fixed.